# Why does v-bind:src not working on server?

Tags: image, vue.js, server, assets, src

This code works correctly on local but not netlify server. Can't read src file.[v-bind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLL6t.png)

Comment: if you use webpack it's generate files before your code executes. So try to define your picture in data via required